# Unity: android.os.DeadObjectException, app crashes on launch

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue building for Android. The build goes fine but the app crashes instantly on launch and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

It seemed to begin out of nowhere, I've gone back to an earlier commit & tried to build with no luck. I also tried deleting Library & other unnecessary folder from the project.

I'm using Unity version 2019.1.8f1 & also tried building with 2019.1.6.f1.

The issue seems to start around here:

```
2019-07-04 14:02:36.577 14403-14420/? E/CRASH: pid: 14403, tid: 14420, name: UnityMain  >>> com.operose.myApp <<<
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.577 3413-3413/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1562238156.573:8057): auid=4294967295 uid=10453 gid=10453 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c197,c257,c512,c768 pid=14403 comm="UnityMain" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.695 3829-3993/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '9d6f41b com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=465
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.695 3829-3993/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '9d6f41b com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.696 3829-4664/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{9d6f41b u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.696 3829-4664/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '9d6f41b com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.696 3829-4664/? V/WindowManager: Remove Window{9d6f41b u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: mSurfaceController=Surface(name=com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity[14403])/@0x95bb7cd mAnimatingExit=false mRemoveOnExit=false mHasSurface=true surfaceShowing=true isAnimationSet=false app-animation=false mWillReplaceWindow=false inPendingTransaction=false mDisplayFrozen=false callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300:280 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3342 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:1209 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.696 3308-3308/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=5862 Removed SurfaceView - com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@ccc8df6@0[14403]#0 (1/78)
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.697 3829-4664/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity[14403])/@0x95bb7cd called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1880 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:838 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2708 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2858 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300:280 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3342 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:1209 <bottom of call stack> 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.697 3308-5213/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=5861 Removed com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity[14403]#0 (0/77)
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.697 3829-6506/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{7e8c8b1 u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t6649}: app died, no saved state
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.702 3308-3343/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=5858 Removed 9d6f41b com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity#0 (0/75)
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.703 3829-4664/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{9d6f41b u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} to null Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2864 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300:280 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3342 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:1209 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.705 3308-3308/? I/Layer: id=5858 onRemoved 9d6f41b com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity#0 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.705 3308-3308/? I/Layer: id=5861 onRemoved com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity[14403]#0 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.706 3308-3308/? I/Layer: id=5863 onRemoved Background for -SurfaceView - com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@ccc8df6@0[14403]#0 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.707 3308-3308/? I/Layer: id=5862 onRemoved SurfaceView - com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@ccc8df6@0[14403]#0 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.707 3829-6506/? I/WindowManager: Cancelling animation restarting=false, leash=null, surface=Surface(name=AppWindowToken{d12e117 token=Token{5299196 ActivityRecord{7e8c8b1 u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t6649}}})/@0xc5cb93, parent=Surface(name=Task=6649)/@0xf15c456
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.708 3308-3343/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=5852 Removed AppWindowToken{d12e117 token=Token{5299196 ActivityRecord{7e8c8b1 u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t6649}}}#0 (0/74)
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.722 3308-3308/? I/Layer: id=5852 onRemoved AppWindowToken{d12e117 token=Token{5299196 ActivityRecord{7e8c8b1 u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t6649}}}#0 
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.833 3829-3869/? D/WindowManager: reportFocusChangedSerialized, focused=false, inTouchMode=true, win=Window{9d6f41b u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
 2019-07-04 14:02:36.833 3829-3869/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{9d6f41b u0 com.operose.myApp/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
     android.os.DeadObjectException
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1143)
 at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:500)
 at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3903)
 at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5426)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Comment: Getting something similar. Ever track this down?

Comment: Same here. Got a DeadObjectException while finishing the Unity Activity